# Importing a Google Sheet including blank cells (default is ragged array)

Tags: import, spreadsheets

I'm able to import data from Google Sheets using e.g.

```
Import["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F3uGfNJH-hch3NfnvZvqzg8vqmMLUkMF2dgAsHPP66s/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&gid=0", "Data"]
```

However, the blank cells are removed, leaving a ragged array. Is there any way of preserving the blank cells in the imported data? (When importing as an Excel sheet, it preserves the blank entries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the URL to request the data in CSV format from Google Sheets (instead of HTML, which is perhaps not the best format for structured tabular data):

```
Import["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F3uGfNJH-hch3NfnvZvqzg8vqmMLUkMF2dgAsHPP66s/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&tq&gid=0", "CSV"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for my toy example above but for some reason doesn't work for the full spreadsheet. (outputs "{{"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\">"}, \
{"<html>"}, {"<head>"}, {"<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" \
content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">"}, {"<title>xxxxxx</title>"}, \
{"</head>"}, {"<body>"}, {"<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" \
cellspacing=\"0\">"}, {"<tr style=\"font-weight: bold; \
background-color: #aaa;\">"}, \
{"<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><\
/td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>...")

Comment: @GregColbourn Did you instruct Google Sheets to output CSV? Notice that I am not using the same URL you posted. I changed `html` to `csv` in it.

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit, yes it works now!

Answer (score 3):

In version 10.1 it appears [`"FullData"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/"FullData".html) will do this, but it also produces some extra fluff that will need to be trimmed.

```
dat = Import[
   "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F3uGfNJH-\
hch3NfnvZvqzg8vqmMLUkMF2dgAsHPP66s/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&gid=0", "FullData"];

dat[[2, 2 ;;, ;; 7]] // Grid // TeXForm
```

$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 341367901 & \text{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367902 & \text{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367903 & \text{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367904 & \text{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367905 & \text{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367906 & \text{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367907 & \text{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367908 & 6.3 & 6.3 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367909 & 5.3 & 11.6 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367910 & 5 & 16.6 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367911 & 5.8 & 22.4 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367912 & 5.4 & 27.8 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 0 \\
 341367913 & 5.4 & 33.2 & 0 & 0 & 278 & 278 \\
 341367914 & 5.3 & 38.5 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 278 \\
 341367915 & 6.2 & 44.7 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 278 \\
 341367916 & 1 & 45.7 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 278 \\
 341367917 & 4 & 49.7 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 278 \\
 341367918 & \text{} & 49.7 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 278 \\
 341367919 & 3.6 & 53.3 & 0 & 0 & 219 & 497 \\
 341367920 & \text{} & 53.3 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 497 \\
 341367921 & \text{} & 53.3 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 497 \\
 341367922 & 3.9 & 57.2 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 497 \\
 341367923 & 7 & 64.2 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 497 \\
 341367924 & 5.9 & 70.1 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 497 \\
 341367925 & 5.6 & 75.7 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 497 \\
 341367926 & 5.9 & 81.6 & 0 & 0 & 260 & 757 \\
 341367927 & \text{} & 81.6 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & 757 \\
\end{array}$

Comment: This works for both my toy example in the OP and my full spreadsheet, thanks!